# pandas dataframe plot set spacing between groups of dates

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, plot

My plot output has all the bar charts neck in neck with each other. I want there to be some spacing to show the groups of plots by date.

Here is what i see
[image]

And here is what i want:
[image]

my code:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(14, 8))
ax.set_xticks(ax.get_xticks()[::2])
df['before'].plot(kind='bar', ax=ax2, color='g', alpha=0.1, label='label before', position=0)
df['after'].plot(kind='bar', ax=ax2, color='r', alpha=0.1, label='label after', position=1)
```

Comment: [This question][1] may cover what you are trying to do.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11597785/3651127

Comment: yes i tried using maxymoo's method but then i got an error that says width is not a parameter