# How to transform a dataframe in order to create a grouped bar plot in python?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, bar-chart, pandas-groupby

I am trying to create a grouped bar plot based on a pandas dataframe (named df).  Can someone explain how to reference each column so I can do something similar to [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40420240/grouped-bar-graph-pandas)?

In R I would have done something like:

```
ggplot(df, aes(factor(live1), bbhome1)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position = "dodge")
```

Heres my python 3.6 code:

```
In [19]: df.groupby(['live1'])['bbhome1'].value_counts()

Out[19]:
live1  bbhome1
1      2          479
       3           104
       1           27
2      2          606
       3            53
       1           10
```

Comment: Could you provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) for testing?

Comment: I'd be happy to, but Im an R user making his first foray into Python and Im not quite sure how to export data structures. Any suggestions?

Comment: did you try `.plot(kind='bar')`

Comment: adding to the comment by [djk47463](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5514476/djk47463) -- if you're using a jupyter notebook then use the magic ````%matplotlib inline```` command to actually see plotted output